# passing entire object as a array dependency vs required properties in hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple doubt in react. As i step into react in some resources people pass the entire object as the array dependency and in some it will pass only the required ones.

For an example i have an object like this

```
const {id, name, number, date} = data
```

In some resources only pass the array deps required ones, but in some other resources they pass the entire object

```
useEffect(() => {
   setState({userId: id, userName: name, userNumber: number})
}, [id, name, number])
```

Or

```
useEffect(() => {
   setState({userId: id, userName: name, userNumber: number})
}, [data])
```

Which is the right approach, second way is much cleaner but since date property doesn't have any impact should we follow it or use the first approach? Apart from this any performance issue or any other impact is there with different types of hooks?

Comment: Depends on the situation. `useEffect` doesn't do a deep compare (hence why things like use-deep-compare-effect exist) which may or may not matter.

Comment: Something like this @DaveNewton https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect isn't. Also if this is the case do i need to do useEffect or the one you mentioned for this kind of object ? I was confused since its an object